# Как записать JSON в файл в Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

На вход приходит `JSON`. Он содержится `Request $request`. Как мне его сохранить в файл при помощи библиотеки `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`? В голову приходит мысль, что может быть можно этот `JSON` с имитировать как будто бы он пришел с `formdata` через `POST`, но как?

> UPD Получилось так (через временный файл):

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, json_encode($request->all()));
$client->addMedia(stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri'])->toMediaCollection();
fclose($temp);
```

Может можно через `laravel` или `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`?

Comment: А обязательно юзать либу эту? Это же элементарно делается

Comment: @Alexxosipov, да так согласовано в проекте.